# Can't share script using Script Lab

Tags: github, office-js, scriptlab

I'm playing with Script Lab in Excel 2016.

This is great stuff!

However, when trying to share a snippet in GitHub, after loggin in from the task pane, the `Authorize` button is disabled. Why is this happening?

See the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for trying out Script Lab!  Due to a recent change on GitHub's side, there is an issue that impacts some [though not all] users when they try to log in on Windows Desktop (which uses IE11 to host the add-in).

We are actively working on a fix, tracked by https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues/248.  I expect it to be finished and in production in a few weeks.

In the meantime, one workaround is for you to go to https://script-lab.azureedge.net/ from a non-IE browser and click "sign in" there. Once you've signed in, close the browser, and try signing in from within Office again. It should bypass this page and succeed.

If you encounter further issues, please feel free to reach out to us on https://github.com/officedev/script-lab

Comment: Hello, thank you so much, this has solved the issue! BTW: I'm reading your book, so I'll come back here with more questions soon :-)